# pgfplots ybar stacked - text instead of number

Tags: pgfplots

I trying to make my first graph with tikz and already succeeded with a big part.

Two things I wasn't able to accomplish:

- Using text label instead of the numbers, I tried it with notes, but it's nuts to figure out where to place them and rearrange when something changes...
- Changing the overall hight of the chart

I hope someone is able to help me :) Thanks!

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}

\begin{comment}



\end{comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
ybar stacked,
width=.9\textwidth,
bar width=.7\textwidth,
nodes near coords,
enlargelimits=0,
ylabel={Spannung in V},
symbolic x coords={tool1
%, tool2, tool3, tool4, tool5, tool6, tool7
    },
xtick=data,

 %  x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
xtick style={draw=none},
xticklabel=\empty
]

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0)};

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,20)};

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4)};

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,12)};

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,12)};

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4)};

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,2)};

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4)};

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,2)};

\coordinate (A) at (5,20);

\coordinate (B) at (5,260);

\coordinate (C) at (5,80);

\coordinate (C) at (5,80);

\end{axis}

\node at (A) {test};

\node at (B) {test 2};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is a `height` key for the `axis` environment, corresponding to the `width` key you have used already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `point meta=explicit symbolic` to the `axis` options, and write the coordinates as `(x,y) [text]`. To set the height, use `height=<length>`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.14} % with compat=1.9 or higher, the bar labels are placed in the center of the bar. 1.14 is the newest version at the moment
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar stacked,
width=.9\textwidth,
height=\textwidth, % <-- added
bar width=.7\textwidth,
point meta=explicit symbolic, % <-- added
nodes near coords,
enlargelimits=0,
ylabel={Spannung in V},
symbolic x coords={tool1
%, tool2, tool3, tool4, tool5, tool6, tool7
    },
xtick=data,
 %  x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
xtick style={draw=none},
xticklabel=\empty
]

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,0) [a]};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,20) [b]};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) [c]};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,12) [d]};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,12) [e]};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) [f]};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,2) [g]};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,4) [h]};
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(tool1,2) [i]};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, the latest version of `pgfplots` is 1.14, so if you're still on 1.8 that is a rather old version.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I've been looking for. Is there a change to move the labels inside of the section instead of above? :)

Comment: The version was in the example code, that I found. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Marcel Starting with the compatibility settings for version 1.9, the default behaviour is to place the labels in the center of the bar, so if you set `compat=1.9` (or higher), that should just work.